# Python split everything between ""s

Tags: python, split, quotes

How do you split everything between ""s in Python? Including the ""s itself?
For example, I want to split something like `print "HELLO"` to just `['print ']` because I split everything in the quotes, including the quotes itself.

Other examples:

1) `print "Hello", "World!"` => `['print ', ', ']`

2) `if "one" == "one": print "one is one"` => `['if ', ' == ', ': print ']`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One way would be, `'print "hello"'.split(chr(34))` where 34 is ASCII for the double-quote character.

Comment: Can you give some more examples of what you mean by "split" here? And preferably what you've already tried?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want to get each part of a string that is not quoted?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney: `chr()` tricks aren't necessary if that's what he was trying to do. `'"'` is a perfectly good way to spell that.

Comment: @Wooble I had just noticed that, d'oh. I forgot to enquote the double-quote (ie, `split('"')`) which raised errors so i opted for the ASCII approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
In [3]: re.split('".*?"', 'print "HELLO"')
Out[3]: ['print ', '']


In [4]: re.split('".*?"', '"Goodbye", "Farewell", and "Amen"')
Out[4]: ['', ', ', ', and ', '']
```

Note the use of `.*?`, the non-greedy all-consuming pattern.

Comment: Good enough of an answer -- at least it sorta works.

Comment: In what way does it not work? I'd be happy to improve the answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm 50 minutes late. Anyways, when I replace `print "..."` w/ `print '...'` -- it just can't interpret '' and "" at the same time. But don't take this personally; all the answers have this bug.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex `'"[^"]*"'` for `re.split`:

Example:

```
txt='''\
print "HELLO"
print "Hello", "World!"
if "one" == "one": print "one is one"
'''

width=len(max(txt.splitlines(), key=len))

for line in txt.splitlines():
    print '{:{width}}=>{}'.format(line, re.split(r'"[^"]*"', line), width=width+1)
```

Prints:

```
print "HELLO"                         =>['print ', '']
print "Hello", "World!"               =>['print ', ', ', '']
if "one" == "one": print "one is one" =>['if ', ' == ', ': print ', '']
```

Comment: method is the same, just the printing is different. Just say `print line, re.split(r'"[^"]*"', line)` then...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'print "Hello"'
>>> re.sub(r'".*?"', r'', text)
'print '
```

To help OP's single quote bug:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'print \'hello\''
>>> re.sub(r'\'.*?\'', r'', text)
'print '
```

Comment: what about `print 'hello'`, not `print "Hello"`?

Comment: Just comment out the `'` sign with `\'`. For example: `text = 'print \'hello\''`
and `re.sub(r'\'.*?\'', r'', text)`